# Async map - callback executing early

Tags: mongodb, async.js

In this async map, the final callback argument is getting called before it logs out 'in events'. (I am just using console.log to avoid over complicating it)...

So where I log 'in last cb' is getting getting logged after all the 'in map' but before events. How do I stop the final callback from firing straight away?

```
const addEvents = (seasons, cb) => {
async.map(seasons, (season, seasonCb) => {
  console.log('in map');
  Model.Events.find({season_id: season._id.toString()}, (err, events) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('in err');
      return seasonCb(err);
    }
    console.log(events, 'events');
  });
  console.log('finish');
  seasonCb(null, season);
}, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('in err');
    return cb(err);
  }
  console.log(seasons, 'in last cb');
  cb(null, seasons);
});
};
```

Comment: Is finish also being called before events?

Comment: Yes it logs in map and then finish straight after for each iteration, then in last cb, then events last.

Comment: solved this by moving seasonCb(null, season) into the find function and adding seasons as an argument to the last function

Answer (score 0):

Find is an asynchronous operation. What you can do is the following:

```
let promise = Model.Events.find(....)

promise.then((error,data) => {
   console.log('finish');
})
```

This should make finish be called after any piece of code you have inside the find.